# Passing arguments to java file from a txt file via shell script

Tags: java, shell

I'm trying to pass a series of test txt files to a java program from a shell script, but it doesn't work. If I pass the arguments to the program from the command line "manually" this works, but if I store them in a txt file and then try to pass it to the program then it doesn't work.

This is the script I'm using right now.

```
clear
mainPath="/Users/massimilianoianniello/IdeaProjects/WeightedMedian"
for i in {1..99}
do
echo "run test on input-$i"
java $mainPath/src/StupidAlg.java < $mainPath/out/input_Test/$i.txt  > $mainPath/out/right_Output_Test/$i.txt
done
```

Comment: Try putting `echo` right before `java` to see exact command line you pass to JVM.

Comment: Alright, this is what it prints.
java /Users/massimilianoianniello/IdeaProjects/WeightedMedian/src/StupidAlg.java

It looks like it dosn't open the files at all...

Comment: Oh, sorry.  You need to put the whole command in quotes, because it does contain redirections.  Something like `echo "java $mainPath/src/ ... Test/$i.txt"`.

Comment: I tried that and it printed the whole string, with < and > too, and the full paths ^^'. I think that java needs a different way to pass arguments with scripts, but I'm not able to find this info...

Comment: Oh.  `<` does not pass anything as arguments, it passes file content as input.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `xargs`:

```
xargs java $mainPath/src/StupidAlg.java < $mainPath/out/input_Test/$i.txt > $mainPath/out/right_Output_Test/$i.txt
```

Comment: Alright, this has worked out. Thank you very much! Now I'll go to inform myself about xargs!